# What is the Difference Between Blazor.Server and Asp.Net Web API?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, webassembly

Blazor is one of those technologies that has me really excited to get started with. I am an experienced Asp.Net MVC and Web API (.Net Framework. not Core) developer.  My first app that I am creating in Blazor is a PWA Web Assembly App with Individual User Accounts Hosted on Asp.Net Core using .Net 5.0. I've chosen to go the hosted route mainly because I want the Asp.Net Identity User Store functionality.

In my newly constructed Blazor Core Hosted Wasm PWA I have three projects.

1. App.Client
2. App.Server
3. App.Library

App.Server in many ways functions like an Api but it is different. One of those differences as far as I can tell is how it authenticates with App.Client. My question is two-fold in the fact that I want to know if other technologies/ clients like Xamarin.Forms can integrate with Blazor's App.Server... or can only Blazor Clients?

Second Question is that App.Server "seems" like an Api... but it is not. What are the differences specifically?

Comment: I don't understand your question, and I don't think I'm the only one.  The title of your question suggests someone with no exposure to Blazor.  The body of your question appears to ask about authentication apart from Blazor.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for the feedback. It is a difficult question to ask because  I am new to Blazor and three are a couple different flavors of Blazor with deployment considerations on those flavors. Please see updated question which hopefully asks it better.

Comment: @Stackoverflow If someone is going to down vote questions they should at the very least be required to say why... Downvotes can still remain anonymous. My biggest complaint about SO is that so many take the time to down vote a question without giving the reason. This creates a hostile environment not a community of professionals for learning... it makes users not want to ask in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Blazor is designed to be used with html and create web content delivery applications. A Web API project has the similarities you've noted because they both exist as a content delivery service via web server. The difference is in the content you're delivering. Blazor is made for web pages, while an API project enables you to deliver data via REST endpoints.

Comment: The original question has been entirely altered, and this answer no longer reflects the new question.

Comment: Actually I disagree. My original question as stated was: "My question is what is the difference between the App.Server project and a new Asp.Net Web API on .Net 5.0?"... I think the confusion came into play because I continuted to ask other questions in trying to gain better understanding of the Blazor Server architecture over API.